# Sort MySQL Select in two ways without ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

Here is the problem: I want my data sorted in 2 differents way without calling two times the database.

Example:

```
SELECT data FROM costumers WHERE x ORDER BY budget, car, home
```

I need this data sorted in this way to do fast some operations.

In the meantime I need also the same data but:

```
ORDER BY home, budget, car
```

I can reorder the data in php or make a second query to my database but I hope there is a simplee and faster way to make it works with MySql.
(maybe the data could be fetch in two differents ways)

Thanks in advance :)

(first time I post, but not first time this website helps me)

Comment: You could sort with PHP after MySQL SELECT. Otherwise use another SELECT.

Comment: My spidersenses tickle and say that you probably can do the operations you do in php in the database too. Anyway, I agree you probably should just query twice, unless it is a hard/long query. Databases are made for sorting, and it is usually the easiest to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this sort in one query .
example if we have col1 and col2. col1 contain strings and col2 contains numbers

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY `col1` DESC, `col2` DESC
```

we assume cols values are

> (col1, col2): (b,3), (a,4), (c,1), (a,1)

after we execute the query above it will return the records in this order

> (col1, col2): (a,1), (a,4), (b,3), (c,1)

note: MySQL uses the first arg of order by as more impotent than second and so on. Even you can sort by triple or more in this way and even the date type could be ordered too.